# Ruby error Webrick or CGI?

Tags: ruby, webrick

I have using `Webrick` + `CGI` and when I instantiate, returns an error: `(offline mode: enter name=value pairs on standard input)`

> ```
> irb(main):001:0> require 'cgi'
> => true
> irb(main):002:0> cgi = CGI.new
> (offline mode: enter name=value pairs on standard input)
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, not an error. That's the way it works.

From the [ruby-docs CGI documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html)

> If the CGI object is not created in a standard CGI call environment (that is, it can’t locate REQUEST_METHOD in its environment), then it will run in “offline” mode. In this mode, it reads its parameters from the command line or (failing that) from standard input

In the irb console, after the `(offline mode: enter name=value pairs on standard input)` message, the console is waiting for you to enter the values. Enter `key value pairs` followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to finish entering data.

```
 irb(main):001:0> require 'cgi'
 => true
 irb(main):002:0> cgi = CGI.new
 (offline mode: enter name=value pairs on standard input)
 name=Prakash
 number=432
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>

```
 => #<CGI:0x007fa4eb2abd30 @options={:accept_charset=>"UTF-8"}, @accept_charset="UTF-8", @multipart=false, @params={"name"=>["Prakash"], "number"=>["432"]}, @cookies={}, @output_cookies=nil, @output_hidden=nil> 
irb(main):003:0>
```

Refer to [CGI Programming Documentation on PLEAC-Ruby](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_ruby/cgiprogramming.html) for further code examples of working with CGI in ruby.

Comment: Ihave using Win7 + Webrick server, my code is:

<% Encoding.compatible?("\xa1".force_encoding("iso-8859-1"), "b") %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pt-br" lang="pt-br">

<head>
<title>Sessão</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>zezzão</h1>
<%
require "cgi"
require "cgi/session"
cgi = CGI::new
session = CGI::Session.new(cgi,"prefix"=>"rubysession")
session["name"]="Darlan"
%>
<%= "Oi, #{session["name"]}"%>
<%
session.close
session.delete
%>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Every time I use CRTL + D?